# Set custom expiration date for certificate (cpp h file format)

Tags: openssl, x509certificate, esp32

Working on a ESP32 custom board, my firmware does https request on two domain (domain1.net, domain2.net). Using `pycert_bearssl.py` tool from SSLCLIENT library i succeed to generate my header file `trust_anchors.h` and make request.

**SSLClient repo**

https://github.com/OPEnSLab-OSU/SSLClient/blob/master/tools/pycert_bearssl/pycert_bearssl.py

I want to use a custom expiration date for these certificate, is that possible and what will be the process ?

ps: one is my domain and the second is not mine.

**trust_anchors.h format**

```
#ifndef _CERTIFICATES_H_
#define _CERTIFICATES_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif


#define TAs_NUM 2

static const unsigned char TA_DN0[] = {
    ...
};

static const unsigned char TA_RSA_N0[] = {
    ...
};

static const unsigned char TA_RSA_E0[] = {
    ...
};

static const unsigned char TA_DN1[] = {
    ...
};

static const unsigned char TA_RSA_N1[] = {
    ...
};

static const unsigned char TA_RSA_E1[] = {
    0x01, 0x00, 0x01,
};

static const br_x509_trust_anchor TAs[] = {
    {
        { (unsigned char *)TA_DN0, sizeof TA_DN0 },
        BR_X509_TA_CA,
        {
            BR_KEYTYPE_RSA,
            { .rsa = {
                (unsigned char *)TA_RSA_N0, sizeof TA_RSA_N0,
                (unsigned char *)TA_RSA_E0, sizeof TA_RSA_E0,
            } }
        }
    },
    {
        { (unsigned char *)TA_DN1, sizeof TA_DN1 },
        BR_X509_TA_CA,
        {
            BR_KEYTYPE_RSA,
            { .rsa = {
                (unsigned char *)TA_RSA_N1, sizeof TA_RSA_N1,
                (unsigned char *)TA_RSA_E1, sizeof TA_RSA_E1,
            } }
        }
    },
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
} /* extern "C" */
#endif

#endif /* ifndef _CERTIFICATES_H_ */
```

My knownlegde of certificate is limited, i used openssl to generate certificate but when i use the python script to generate the h file, it returns error: no root certificate founded for domain1.net and domain2.net

Comment: An SSL cert expiry data is set during cert generation or when the cert is issued(if you purchase from a trust issuer), it is not something you can change dynamically via program.